# Is there a .NET PCL compliant implementation of CommandLineToArgv? string to argv[]?

Tags: mono, .net-core, portable-class-library

I would like to parse stored command line calls into their individual command tokens (so I can pass them to Mono.Options).  In the past I'd pinvoke CommandLineToArgvW, but thats not an option in my current environment.  Is there a PCL way to parse a command string into individual argments?

Update:  I am not trying to get the current process's arguments.  I have string values which represent command line calls, I want to parse those existing string into arguments.

Comment: Well, don't do that, use Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().  It is about as portable as a ten ton weight, not a heckofalot of command line parsing in a web or mobile app.

Comment: Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() returns the arguments for the current process.  I have an existing string I want to parse into arguments.

Comment: You can grab the simple Tokenizer class from https://github.com/nelyom/cmdLineTokenizer which is modeled after `CommandLineToArgvW` and its kookie ruleset